# SQL query to set my auto increment column ( id ) to zero or reset the value of auto increment field

Tags: mysql, auto-increment, reset

I want a query which can set an auto increment value in mysql database to 0.

In my case i want a column called "id" to be reset to 0.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE some_table AUTO_INCREMENT=0
```

If you want to delete all records from your table and restart auto-index at 0, you might be tempted to run a DELETE query, followed by the above example, setting the auto increment value to 0. There is a shortcut, however:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE some_table
```

Comment: The `TRUNCATE` syntax also ignores any foreign key constraints which can otherwise cause `DELETE` to fail (if you have a cross-reference within a table, for example.)

Answer (score 3):

ALTER TABLE some_table AUTO_INCREMENT=0  doesn't work

do: ALTER TABLE some_table AUTO_INCREMENT=1

(MySQL version: 5.5.29)

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename_here AUTO_INCREMENT = value_here
```